# Drools workbench: Create multiple kie-sessions using Kie Server Java Client API

Tags: drools, drools-kie-workbench

I am using **Drools workbench 7.17 integrated with Kie execution server**. I have created a project within workbench and the project is deployed on kie execution server.

I have **configured kie-base and kie-session in project's settings**. Defined stateful kie-session as KieSession. I am using Kie Server Java Client API to insert facts into engine.

I am able to do lookup on KieSession. I am going to receive the data for different users and I want to **create and maintain separate sessions for each user**. When the fact is inserted for the existing user then I should be able to **reload kie-session** associated with that user.

Is there any way through which iI can achieve this using drools workbench and kie-execution server? I couldn't find any example in kie server documentation to create new session using kie server java client api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems such thing is not possible with kie-execution server, but looks like similar thing can be achieved using kieSession pool when using drools/jbpm in embedded mode.

Comment: When you say kieSession pool when using drools/jbpm in embedded mode does this mean loading Kie JAR into application code and then creating KieSession. I tried this approach [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632881/how-to-integrate-kie-workbench-6-1-0-final-drools-guvnor-project-with-java-app/28230876#28230876) but it's not working for me. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: You can load individual assets(DRL,BPMN) from filesystem or from classpath. Take a look at [code](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-examples-api/kiefilesystem-example/src/main/java/org/drools/example/api/kiefilesystem/KieFileSystemExample.java).

Answer (score 1):

If this is the case, a new session is created each time you make a call. No stateful sessions are maintained in the kie-server.

You have 3 solutions :

1) develop a kie-server extension for that but it is difficult to cluster(you will have to serialize the kie session)

2) Use the java API of drools to run the rules on the client-side.

3) make your rules so that the data generated by the rule execution contains the status of your calculation so that calling back drools with initial data + all generated by rules is equivalent to keeping a stateful session for your client session. Drools is quick on inserting data. But now all depends on how much data your insert. A few thousand is nothing.

Regards